# iOS Button not clickable after Animating to reveal panel

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UIView that has a container view hidden off the frame that I reveal via animation when you click a button.  However, once the animation completes I cannot interact with any objects in the frame that just animated into view.

**View Hierarchy**

[image: viewhierarchy]

**View layout**

[image]

You will note two things about the view layout

1. the Container view is outside of the normal view frame/bounds
2. it has a fixed height (those are the constraint likes you see)

I tried expanding the frame height and bounds in order to accommodate the height of the container view, but after the animation I still can't interact with views in the Container.

What do I need to modify to allow interactions to work once this view animates into view?

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide a simple project, so I can download it and check what is the problem?

Comment: The answer to this question got me to where I needed to be: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770743/capturing-touches-on-a-subview-outside-the-frame-of-its-superview-using-hittest.  I made my root view a custom subclass of UIView that contains the answer's implementation of `hitTest:withEvent:`.