# UIPanGestureRecognizer not being fired for UIImageView outside its SuperView area?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, draggable, uipangesturerecognizer

I have the following UI on an iPad app:

[image]

Here is an explanation of what's going on:

1. Blue area is the View attached to the (displayed) ViewController.
2. Yellow area is an UIImageView where users can drag items around (what I call the live area).  Yellow is a subview of blue area.
3. Red item is an UIImageView that has a UIPanGestureRecognizer attached.  Its a subview of yellow area.
4. Red item can be dragged, as long as the dragging starts from inside the live (yellow) area.

On the situation on the image shown above, I want to be able to drag the red item from any point on its surface. (not only from the area where it intersects the (yellow) area)

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Views don't respond to touches when they are outside the bounds of their superview. You can fix the problem by making the red view a subview of the blue view instead of the yellow one.

Answer (score 0):

rdelmar has the cleanest way to do that.

But if you want to keep your view architecture, you can make a YellowClass, subclass of UIImageView for your yellow view. And implement the following code in your YellowClass:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{   
    if (!self.clipsToBounds && !self.hidden && self.alpha > 0) {
        for (UIView *subview in self.subviews.reverseObjectEnumerator) {
            CGPoint subPoint = [subview convertPoint:point fromView:self];
            UIView *result = [subview hitTest:subPoint withEvent:event];
            if (result != nil) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

YellowView subviews that are outside yellowView will respond to touch.

Read from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770743/capturing-touches-on-a-subview-outside-the-frame-of-its-superview-using-hittest).