# UIButton is not getting touch even in full area

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton, touch-up-inside

I have `UIBUtton` in `UICollectionViewCell` as show in image. I had set **touchUpInside** Action in xib. I had set background image of button is pink and lable as yellow. `UIButton` comes at top of the label. Now the problem is that `UIButton` in not getting touch event in pink area it only get touch events on orange area. why it is so.

```
- (IBAction)checkButtonTap:(id)sender event:(id)event
{
    DLog(@"%s",__func__);
}
```

[image]

---

O a hidden view is overlapping the button due to which it is touch event was not reaching to the button.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be sure I understand your issue, you have your `UICollectionView` in yellow and your `UIbutton` in pink, correct ?

If so, it seems you want to intercept the touchUpInside event outside your button's superview in yellow. You can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770743/capturing-touches-on-a-subview-outside-the-frame-of-its-superview-using-hittest) which deal with kind of problem.

Even if you finally find the solution to your problem, to clarify my answer, if you want to interact with an `UIButton` which is not inside its superview's frame, you may need to need to implement the method `- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` of the superview (here the `UICollectionViewCell`):

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
if (!self.clipsToBounds && !self.hidden && self.alpha > 0) {
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews.reverseObjectEnumerator) {
        CGPoint subPoint = [subview convertPoint:point fromView:self];
        UIView *result = [subview hitTest:subPoint withEvent:event];
        if (result != nil) {
            return result;
        }
    }
}

return nil;
}
```

(thanks Noam!)

Comment: the UILabel is in yellow not UICollectionView

Answer (score 0):

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:)];
    [buttonname addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    buttonname.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

- (IBAction)imageTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
  if(gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized) {
      [buttonname  becomeFirstResponder];
  }
  }

Comment: why i should add a tap gesture on a button?

Answer (score 0):

O  sorry, there was hidden view that is overlapping the button due to which  touch event was not reaching to the button.