# swift: subview not tappable outside parent view

Tags: swift, hittest

I have a [DKDropMenu](https://github.com/davecom/DKDropMenu) implemented on ios project. Everything works just fine except it is not tappable outside parent views bounds.

I tried to use HitTest method but its not working. Can someone guide me how to solve this issue?

Comment: Hi, @NarendraOjha, did you manage to resolve this issue? It looks like you may want to add the hit test to DKDropMenu. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770743/capturing-touches-on-a-subview-outside-the-frame-of-its-superview-using-hittest