# User interactions on UIPickerview outside of its superview in swift

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, frame, uipickerview

I have `UIPickerView` inside my view hierarchy, but its not directly inside of my view, when I try to interact with Picker View it doesn't respond. I've tried some answers from StackOverflow but they did not work.

This is one of the answers I found and I thought it would work, I've tried it but it did not work, there is a swift answer in this article and i tried that one.

[Capturing touches on a subview outside the frame of its superview using hitTest:withEvent:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770743/capturing-touches-on-a-subview-outside-the-frame-of-its-superview-using-hittest)

Could anybody help me? I can give you some more information if you'll need it

Any Suggestions or links to follow?

Comment: I have UIPickerView inside my view hierarchy, but its not directly inside of my view, - what does this mean? What is my view? - the view controller's view?

Comment: It's not in your view yet you can see it when you build and run?

Comment: yes its in the view controller view but the position is outside of that view