# Receiving touch events outside bounds

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

There have been similar questions before and I have referred to [Capturing touches on a subview outside the frame of its superview using hitTest:withEvent:](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11770743/1321873) and [Delivering touch events to a view outside the bounds of its parent view](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa2013/qa1812.html). But they do not seem to answer my particular problem.

I have a custom control with the following structure:

```
+-------------------------------+
|           UIButton            |
+-------------------------------+
|                          |
|                          |
|        UITableView       |
|                          |
|                          |
+------------------------- +
```

The custom control overrides the `UIButton` subclass and adds the `UITableView` as its subView. The idea is to have the whole control act like a dropdown. When the `UIButton` is pressed, the `UITableView` will dropdown and enable selection of a choice.

This all works fine with the `hitTest` overridden in `UIButton` as described in the Apple's Q&A link above, if the control is an immediate child of the topmost `UIView`.  However, if the control is in another view hierarchy, the `UITableView` is not receiving touch events.

The following is the hitTest code used:

```
override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    // Convert the point to the target view's coordinate system.
    // The target view isn't necessarily the immediate subview
    let pointForTargetView = self.spinnerTableView.convertPoint(point, fromView:self) 

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.spinnerTableView.bounds, pointForTargetView)) {
        // The target view may have its view hierarchy,
        // so call its hitTest method to return the right hit-test view
        return self.spinnerTableView.hitTest(pointForTargetView, withEvent:event);
    }
    return super.hitTest(point, withEvent: event)
}
```

**Edit:**

I apologise for not having been able to look at the answers and check if they resolve the issue, due to some other tasks that require immediate attention. I shall check them and accept one that helps. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 5):

As you stated:

> However, if the control is in another view hierarchy, the UITableView
>   is not receiving touch events.

Even if you made it working what if you have subviewed this control under another UIView??

This way we have a burden of converting points for the view hierarchy, my suggestion is that, as you can see in [this control](https://github.com/NeverHopeless/NHAutoCompleteTextField/blob/master/NHAutoCompleteTextBox/NHClasses/NHHelper/NHAutoCompleteTextField.m), it adds the tableview on the same hierarchy where the control itself is present. (e.g., it adds the table view on the controller where this control was added)

A part from the link:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self setupSuggestionList];
    [suggestionListView setHidden:NO];

    // Add list to the super view.
    if(self.dataSourceDelegate && [self.dataSourceDelegate isKindOfClass:UIViewController.class])
    {
        [((UIViewController *)self.dataSourceDelegate).view addSubview:suggestionListView];
    }

    // Setup list as per the given direction
    [self adjustListFrameForDirection:dropDownDirection];
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Makes sense. I did not try it, though.

Answer (score 5):

I think you should overridden `pointInside` implement:

```
class Control: UIButton {

    var dropdown: Bool = false

    override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        if dropdown {
            return CGRectContainsPoint(CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: self.bounds.width, self.bounds.height + spinnerTableView.frame.height), point)
        }
        return super.pointInside(point, withEvent: event)
    }
}
```

like this, superview call control's `hittest` when touch outside control bounds, it won't return nil.

But there are still a problem， if the control is in another view hierarchy, the UITableView may not receiving touch events.

I think this problem is normal，you can't decide other view's pointInside or not which under control, if the control superview `hitTest` return nil, the control `hitTest` method will not be called.
Unless you overridden all view `pointInside` method which under the control, but it is unrealistic.

Answer (score 3):

I was thinking about the `UIResponder` , something like:

```
override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        // Convert the point to the target view's coordinate system.
        // The target view isn't necessarily the immediate subview

        var responder: UIResponder = self
        while responder.nextResponder() != nil {
            responder = responder.nextResponder()!
            if responder is UITableView {
                // Got UITableView
                break;
            }
        }
        let pointForTargetView = responder.convertPoint(point, fromView:self)
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(responder.bounds, pointForTargetView)) {
            // The target view may have its view hierarchy,
            // so call its hitTest method to return the right hit-test view
            return self.responder.hitTest(pointForTargetView, withEvent:event);
        }
        return super.hitTest(point, withEvent: event)
}
```

If this method don't work, try to `convertPoint` with superview:

When you are sure that `self.spinnerTableView` is not nil and it is your table, do:

```
let pointForTargetView = self.spinnerTableView.superView.convertPoint(point, fromView:self)
```

Comment: Nope, the issue with the previous implementation was that the point was not correctly converted to the `UITableView` co-ordinate system. So even in the case above, `CGRectContainsPoint` does not identify the point to be within the `UITableView` bounds.

Comment: Thanks, but I need a generic way to do this. Irrespective of the number of hierarchical levels the control is in.

Comment: I don't understand if you have solve your problem or need only an high level syntax code to do it. As you have comment now , seems the issue was solved and you know how to do but you want a method to cover all possibilities superviews..can you explain better your comment thank you (sorry Im not english so maybe anything can be escaping..)

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguous comment. The updated answer did not solve the problem. From what I understand, you are suggesting to convert the point from the superview's co-ordinate system. This *may* work if the control is one level deeper. I need a working solution **AND** it should work in all cases. I will try to post a sample project so that you can try out your suggestions before posting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to subClass UIView,and use it as your UIViewController's root view.

```
class HitTestBottomView: UIView {

  override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {

    if  let hitTestView  =    self.getHitTestButtonFrom(self){
        let pointForHitTestView = hitTestView.convertPoint(point, fromView: self)
        let pointForHitTestTableView = hitTestView.spinnerTableView.convertPoint(point, fromView: self)

        if CGRectContainsPoint(hitTestView.bounds, pointForHitTestView) ||  CGRectContainsPoint(hitTestView.spinnerTableView.bounds, pointForHitTestTableView){
            return hitTestView.hitTest(pointForHitTestView, withEvent: event)
        }
    }

    return super.hitTest(point, withEvent: event)
  }

  func getHitTestButtonFrom(view:UIView) ->HitTestButton?{
    if let testView = view as? HitTestButton {
        return testView
    }

    for  subView  in view.subviews {
        if let testView = self.getHitTestButtonFrom(subView) {
            return testView
        }
    }
    return nil
  }
}
```

Comment: The idea was to use the control as a reusable component within any UIView hierarchy. Hence, using it as the root view is not a preferred solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement

```
func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool
```

for your `UIButton` and check `UITableView` bounds. Because `hitTest` first checks if this tap point is within your view's bounds then calls `hitTest` for your view. so you have to implement `pointInside` and return true for your bounds.

WWDC for [advanced scroll views and touch handling techniques wwdc](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/235/)

Comment: This was the first thing I did. But as explained, the issue is in converting the point to the table view's co-ordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution Swift 5.2**

you need to override this in superview of the UIVIew or button where it is palced. if UIView is V and you placed uiview V1 or Button B1 in V, you need to put the code in UIView V.

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
       guard !clipsToBounds && !isHidden && alpha > 0 else {
           return nil
       }
       
       for member in subviews.reversed() {
           let subPoint = member.convert(point, from: self)
           guard let result = member.hitTest(subPoint, with: event) else {
               continue
           }
           return result
       }
       return nil
   }
```