# Button anchored to InputAccessoryView working only in its frame

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3, uibutton, inputaccessoryview

**Setup**

I implemented an `inputAcessoryView` in a `UIViewController` via the following:

```
override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {

    get {

        return bottomBarView
    }
}
override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {

    return true
}

fileprivate lazy var bottomBarView: UIView = {

    let view = UIView()
    let separatorLineView = UIView()

    view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height / 9)
    view.backgroundColor = .white

    /...

    separatorLineView.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 220, g: 220, b: 220, a: 1)
    separatorLineView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(separatorLineView)
    separatorLineView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    separatorLineView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    separatorLineView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    separatorLineView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true

    view.addSubview(self.photoButton)
    self.photoButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    self.photoButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: separatorLineView.centerYAnchor, constant: -12).isActive = true
    self.photoButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.width / 4.5).isActive = true
    self.photoButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.width / 4.5).isActive = true

    return view
}()
```

`photoButton` implements an action on `.touchUpInside`.

**The issue**

The button is only clickable in the part included in `inputAccessoryView`'s frame: if I click on it on the part that's outside, nothing happens.

Is there any quick way to make it work like so ?

I have tried moving the `photoButton` out of `bottomBarView` and adding it to the view instead however:

- I need `photoButton` to be "anchored" to the `inputAccessoryView`, but it seems `inputAccessoryView` doesn't have anchor properties from within the view ? (I can only access their `frame` properties via bang unwrapping)
- When I do so, `photoButton` is partly hidden behind `inputAccessoryView` and I can't bring it forward with `view.bringSubview(ToFront:)`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had this problem myself in my own work over the past couple days.

You need to implement your own `hitTest` UIResponder method for your `inputAcessoryView`.  Something that might look like this:

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, 
        with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {

    if self.photoButton.frame.contains(point) {
        return self.photoButton
    }

    return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
}
```

More information can be seen [in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11770743/981049).

Comment: Hey Michael, thanks for pointing to this answer (missed it somehow). Happy to report it worked, but had to implement this with `bottomBarView` being a subview of my controller's view and remove the `inputAccessoryView` as it is not a subview of the controller's view and therefore was still not taking into account taps in a button outside of its frame. Would gladly like to hear if you have any idea to make it work with an `inputAccessoryView` ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have is that the `inputAccessoryView` (`bottomBarView` for you) has no height. All of the subviews you're adding are therefore outside of its bounds. If you were to set `clipsToBounds = true`, you would see that everything disappears.

The issue with this, as you're seeing, is that those subviews aren't getting touch events since they're outside the bounds of their superview. From Apple's docs:

> If a touch location is outside of a view’s bounds, the hitTest:withEvent: method ignores that view and all of its subviews. As a result, when a view’s clipsToBounds property is NO, subviews outside of that view’s bounds are not returned even if they happen to contain the touch.

[Understanding Event Handling, Responders, and the Responder Chain](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/understanding_event_handling_responders_and_the_responder_chain?preferredLanguage=occ)

The solution is to get the `inputAccessoryView` to be the correct height. `self.view.frame.height / 9` is `0` in your example, since the frame has not been set by the time you're using it.

Instead, create a `UIView` subclass, with the following important parts:

```
class BottomBarView: UIView {

    init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        autoresizingMask = .flexibleHeight

        let someView = UIView()
        addSubview(someView)
        someView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        someView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        someView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        someView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
        someView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive = true

        // In this case, the top, bottom, and height constraints will 
        // determine the height of the inputAccessoryView
        someView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric, height: 0)
    }
}
```

Try adding a button. You'll see that now it gets a touch event, since it's within the bounds of it's superview now.