# iOS Swift 3 - UIButton on UIStackView in UICollectionViewCell is not responding to tap events (no interaction)

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uistackview

I have a [UICollectionViewCell](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcell) subclass which has a [UIStackView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview) on it.
The StackView is populated with [UIButtons](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton) and everything looks fine 
however the buttons are untappable.

*If I layout the same buttons on a [UIScrollView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview) (for the sake of experiment) instead of on a stackview, the buttons respond fine so it seems like something with the stackview is causing the issue*

Any ideas?

[image: My Layout]

Here is the code of how I add buttons to the StackView

```
 func prepareStackView(buttonsArray: Array<UIButton>) {


    var rect:CGRect = (stackView?.frame)!
    rect.size.width = btn.frame.size.width * buttonsArray.count
    stackView?.frame = rect //The frame of the stackview is set as such so that it looks exactly like I want


    //Add all the buttons
    for btn in buttonsArray {
            //The buttons already have their selectors set
            stackView?.addArrangedSubview(btn)
    }


 }
```

Comment: disable the stackview interaction as stackview.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

Comment: Why? Then none of its arranged views will be interactable anyway

Comment: i think stackview override the interactable property of button. So, I had said that and have you tried it?

Comment: Tried. Didn't work

Comment: Download my demo app https://www.dropbox.com/s/7j6pyca3i4y13mt/MyDemoApp.zip?dl=0
Look at view controller "SpotInfoViewController" >> "buttonClicked"

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for UIButton to respond to click event:

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {

    if clipsToBounds || isHidden || alpha == 0 {
        return nil
    }

    for subview in subviews.reversed() {
        let subPoint = subview.convert(point, from: self)
        if let result = subview.hitTest(subPoint, with: event) {
            return result
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Helpful link:

[Capturing touches on a subview outside the frame of its superview using hitTest:withEvent:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770743/capturing-touches-on-a-subview-outside-the-frame-of-its-superview-using-hittest)

I have also encountered similar problem and able to resolve. Please check my post where I have described the scenario of this type of cause and tried to explain how I was able to resolve.

[UIButton is not clickable after first click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46042830/uibutton-is-not-clickable-after-first-click)