# Unexpected nil index path in _shouldShowMenuForCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

Does anyone know what is going on with this problem? My cell stop swiping because of this.

> [Assert] Unexpected nil index path in
>   _shouldShowMenuForCell:, this should never happen. Cell ; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 97.5; 375 130); alpha = 0; hidden = YES;
>   autoresize = W; gestureRecognizers = ; layer
>   = >

Help !!!

Comment: Care to share some code?

Comment: It isn't anything special, only VC with UItableView. Cell swiping I created using gesture recognizer implemented in subclass of UITableViewCell and works fine, problem starting when this log is showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found solution even with creating swipe cell using gesture recognizer, in my case the problem ("Unexpected nil index path in _shouldShowMenuForCell:, this should never happen. ") was appearing because of this function:

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        for subview in self.subviews.reversed() {
            if subview.frame.contains(point) {
                return subview
            }
        }

        return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
}
```

tip: Working solution of:
[Capturing touches on a subview outside the frame of its superview using hitTest:withEvent:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770743/capturing-touches-on-a-subview-outside-the-frame-of-its-superview-using-hittest)

Answer (score 2):

I change swiping method from gestureRecognizer to ScrollView and everything works perfect.

Answer (score 2):

If your cell is created by - 
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:self options:nil] lastObject];

AND using addSubview to display it. This problem will occur.

My solution is using "addSubview:cell.contentView" BUT NO "addSubview:cell"

Comment: I did the same but not working, `tableViewCell.contentView.addSubview(tableViewCell.webView)` do you have any more suggestion ?