# Why does clipsToBounds prevent the subviews to be touched?

Tags: ios, swift, touch-event, hittest

Let's say you have a superview that has a smaller size than its subview. You set the `clipsToBound` property of the superview to `false`. If you tap on the protruding area of the subview that is outside of the bounds of the superview, why does the hit test return nil?

My understanding is that the hit test starts from the subview and work its way up to the superview. So why does the property of the superview that is to be tested later than the subview matter? Or does the hit test start from the root to tree views like the view controller -> the main view -> subviews?

I found a custom hit-test from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14875673/10116367), which does allow you to tap on the subview's area outside of the bounds of the superview, but I'm not sure why reversing the order of subviews make a difference(it works, I'm just not sure why). My example even only has one subview.

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let superview = CustomSuperview(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: .init(width: 100, height: 100)))
    let subview = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: .init(width: 200, height: 200)))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(self.superview)
        self.superview.backgroundColor = .red
        self.superview.clipsToBounds = false
        
        self.superview.addSubview(self.subview)
        self.subview.backgroundColor = .blue
         
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped))
        self.subview.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
    
    @objc func tapped(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        print("tapped")
    }
}

class CustomSuperview: UIView {
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {

        if clipsToBounds || isHidden || alpha == 0 {
            return nil
        }

        for subview in subviews.reversed() {
            let subPoint = subview.convert(point, from: self)
            if let result = subview.hitTest(subPoint, with: event) {
                return result
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My understanding is that the hit test starts from the subview and work its way up to the superview.

Then your understanding is completely wrong. Let’s fix that. First, let's clear up some other misunderstandings:

- The `reversed` is a total red herring; it has nothing to do with it. The subviews are *always* tested in reverse order, because a subview in front needs to take precedence over a subview behind.
- The `clipsToBounds` is a total red herring too. All it does is change whether you can *see* a subview outside its superview; it does not have any effect on whether you can *touch* a subview outside its superview.

Okay, so how does this work? Let's take view V which contains a subview A. Let's suppose that A is outside V. Assume you can see A, and you tap A.

Now hit-testing begins. But here's the thing: it starts at the level of the *window*, and works its way *down* the view hierarchy. So the window starts by interrogating its subviews; there is just one, the *main view of the view controller*.

So now we recurse, and the main view of the view controller interrogates *its* subviews. One of those is V. "Hey, V, was the tap inside you?" "No!" (You have to agree that that is the correct answer, because we already said that A is outside V.)

So the main view of the view controller *gives up* on V, and never finds out that the tap was on A, because we never recursed down that far. So it reports back up the chain: "The tap was not on *any* of my subviews, so I have to report that the tap was on *me*." The tap has *fallen through* to the view controller's main view.

But you can *change* that behaviour by *overriding* the implementation of `hitTest`:

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with e: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    if let result = super.hitTest(point, with:e) {
        return result
    }
    for sub in self.subviews.reversed() {
        let pt = self.convert(point, to:sub)
        if let result = sub.hitTest(pt, with:e) {
            return result
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: OK now I get it. It's like that depth-first traversal of a tree where the superview is tested first, but when it comes to siblings, the last one be added get tested first.

Comment: It's not the adding order that is being reversed, it is the _drawing_ order. Subviews come in back-to-front order, because that's how we want them drawn. But we want them _tested_ in front-to-back order, because that's how we want them touched.